# Optical character recognition - how it works?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I was interested in symbol recognition recently and I start to read about it in the Internet. I got more information about preprocessing and segmentation stages, but all of it is just prestage for transformation from image to string. And all notes from Internet led me to using ready solution, like Tesseract, which do all works behind interface. However, I interested in detailed description of this process and I want to get all steps of this transformation.
Can anybody give me some links to exhaustive literature or articles about this theme? For example, Tesseract image_to_string() function algorithm. I will thankful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is the [github page of Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), especially the Wiki page of Tesseract.

Or if you want to recognize specific symbol, you can make your own recognizer using neural networks, follow this [step-to-step tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0).